# How to pass input type arguments to a Mutation in graph QL Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graphql

I am trying to learn GraphQL with Neo4j. I am having trouble understanding how to generate a graphql query to update a relationship between nodes

Below are the Mutations auto generated by neo4j-graphql.js  to create a relationship between two objects

[image]

Below is the schema

[image]

It would be really great if someone can explain how to pass the arguments for the AddUSAIsequal mutation.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
mutation{
  AddUSAIsequal(from:{
    fieldFormat:""
  }
    to:{
      createdDate:""
    }
  ){
    from{
      fieldName
    }
    to{
      fieldName
    }
  }
}
```